# drupal:creating relation betwen two content types in Relationships

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, content-type

How to create a new relation in two views between two content type nodes 
1.Question content type
2.Answer content type
The title of the answer content type should be fetched from the question content type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question right, but I would first use the [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) module to create the relationship in the content type (add a node reference field in the answer pointing to the question - the [Node Reference URL Widget](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module provides a good UI way of doing the entry part (i.e. put an Add Answer link on the question node automatically).

Then in whatever View you have, you can use the relationships (or reverse relationship) to link the Question to the Answer (or the answer to the question).  Or you could use Contextual Filters with an [entity attached view](http://drupal.org/project/eva) to get all the answers for a question and show them in a view.